# Numeric value in front of type/Object's parameter name

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I feel so dumb right now, but...

I am facing an issue where I am trying to fetch data from API but the api has JSON object parameters with numeric values in front of them. Something like `{1stxxxx: 'value', 2ndxxx: 'value'}`

But that gives me error in eslint:

> An identifier or keyword cannot immediately follow a numeric literal.

So the type I have is something like this and the eslint doesn't like the number in front of `type` parameter names and I do not know, and could not find the eslint rule for that case, to turn it off. And that in ReactNative gives the above unavoidable error:

```
type MyObject = {
  1stXxx?: string;
};
```

What would be my options? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes, as you would in JavaScript objects:

```
type MyObject = {
  "1stXxx"?: string;
};
```

Comment: Noooo way! i feel myself so dumb now. Thank you very much ‍♂️ 

Comment: Alternative way: `Partial<Record<'1stXxx', string>>`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine your idea sounds interesting but I didn't quite catch that. What is `Partial` and What is `Record`? From where should you import them? Would that help me not to use "`['1stXxx']`" to access the variable?

Comment: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) you can find docs about using `Partial` and `Record` and [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGRdvm) you can find my example